# Name shows up as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I have been working on a kick command, and I pretty much got the whole thing working, except when I have the bot send a message telling us who was kicked, it just shows up as "undefined was kicked"

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('grimm!kick')) {
        var member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
            const kicked = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff6700')
            .setDescription(`${message.mentions.members.first.username} Was kicked`)
            message.channel.send(kicked)
            member.kick()
} else {
            const notKicked = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff6700')
            .setDescription(`${message.author.username}! you do not have permission to kick people! you must have the "Kick Members" Permission to use this command`)
            message.channel.send(notKicked)
}}});
```

I have tried "member.username" and that still wont work

Could someone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong, so I wont make this same mistake again? Thanks!

Comment: `message.mentions.members.first.username` -> `message.mentions.members.first().username`?

Comment: your code already has `var member = message.mentions.members.first()` so use it over the other call `.setDescription(\`${member.username} Was kicked\`)`

Comment: I have tried both of those methods, but both times, the name just poped up as undefined still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in this code.

1. You are using first as a property, not a method.
2. the property `username` doesnt exist on The GuildMember class.
   what you are looking for is GuildMember.user.username.

replace

```js
.setDescription(`${message.mentions.members.first.username} Was kicked`)
```

with

```js
.setDescription(`${message.mentions.members.first().user.username} Was kicked`)
```